# Javascript: sending variables from client to express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I cannot send a variable from a js application to node.js server.
Here is my code:

```js
//client side

$.get('http://smart-shopper.ro/messages?from=lastGeneralTimeStamp', datas => {
      console.log("data este " + datas)
})
//and server side:

app.get('/messages/:from', (req, res) => {
    let lastGeneralTimeStamp = req.parms.from;
     var sql = `select * from chat where data > '${lastGeneralTimeStamp}' order by id ASC `;
    con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
       // res.send(result);
       res.send(result);
        console.log(result)
    })
})
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Use `req.query` as indicated in the answer below. Notwithstanding that, you've misspelled `req.params` (you wrote `req.parms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing data as querystring, but your API on server side is listening data as param.

Change the request in client side:

```js
//client side

$.get('http://smart-shopper.ro/messages/lastGeneralTimeStamp', datas => {
      console.log("data este " + datas)
})
//and server side:

app.get('/messages/:from', (req, res) => {
    let lastGeneralTimeStamp = req.params.from;
     var sql = `select * from chat where data > '${lastGeneralTimeStamp}' order by id ASC `;
    con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
       // res.send(result);
       res.send(result);
        console.log(result)
    })
})
```

Or server side API:

```js
//client side

$.get('http://smart-shopper.ro/messages?from=lastGeneralTimeStamp', datas => {
      console.log("data este " + datas)
})
//and server side:

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
    let lastGeneralTimeStamp = req.query.from;
     var sql = `select * from chat where data > '${lastGeneralTimeStamp}' order by id ASC `;
    con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
       // res.send(result);
       res.send(result);
        console.log(result)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You are doing GET to: 
http://smart-shopper.ro/messages?from=lastGeneralTimeStamp

which is query param with the name from. To access query params you cant use

```
let lastGeneralTimeStamp = req.parms.from;
```

but rather

```
req.query.<name_of_query_param>
```

in your case its:

```
req.query.from
```

Comment: In addition, `req.params` was misspelled (it was `req.parms`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `req.query` instead of `req.params`.

[According to this documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) that's how you access the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Possible typo: `req.params.from` not `req.parms.from`